# Pull into pieces=tear

Tags: meaning

I've come across an exercise in a workbook of the American English. It requires to write the words given in the box next to their definitions. The words in the box are wife, rock, row, whirlpool, tear, hero. Can "pull into pieces" be similar to "tear" by meaning? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Tearing something (like cloth or paper) involves pulling it into pieces. See the *verb form* of "tear" in the Cambridge Dictionary [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/tear).